# How to recover Windows 10 product key from Ubuntu

Tags: windows-10

I've installed Ubuntu in one disk and windows 10 is in another disk. I'm not able to boot into windows 10. So to reinstall, I need that windows 10 key. How can I recover windows 10 key from my Ubuntu? I can able to mount my Windows disk in Ubuntu.